# Unable to create AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment in either command line or admin dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy a "Hello, world" Rails app (Rails v 5.0.1, Ruby v 2.3.1) to AWS for the purposes of learning about AWS.

I have created an IAM user in the AWS Elastic Beanstalk dashboard, and I've verified that the user has one access ID and secret access key.  I've ensured these two credentials are stored in environment variables in my local machine, and for completeness I've also ensured these same values are correct in the ~/.aws/credentials file.  I have gone through the steps of creating a new application in the UI, however whenever I click "Create Application", I see the following error at the top of the screen:

```
Validation Error
Configuration validation exception: AWS Elastic Beanstalk could not communicate with Amazon EC2 to determine whether to create a custom security group for Elastic Load Balancing.
```

My IAM user is a member of the "AdministratorAccess" and "AWSElasticBeanstalkFullAccess" permissions groups.

When creating the application, I went through the following steps:

1) Selected "Web server environment" in the "Choose environment tier" menu.
2) In the "Create a new environment" menu, I choose "Ruby" as the platform and "Sample Application" under the "Application code" selection.

Similarly, when I nagivate to my project directory in the command line, and I run "eb create dev-env", I see the following:

```
MacBook-Pro-5:beanstalk richiethomas$ eb create dev-env
WARNING: You have uncommitted changes.
Creating application version archive "app-e4da-170116_145453".
Uploading beanstalk/app-e4da-170116_145453.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
ERROR: API Call unsuccessful. Status code returned 401
```

EDIT: The same 401 response is returned even when I have no uncommitted changes.

Can anyone illuminate what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Im trying to follow your problem.  Are you going by the steps layed out here:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html  ?

Comment: @Taterhead yes with a few exceptions.  I used Homebrew instead of pip to install awsebcli.  Also, the "puma" gem was already in my Gemfile (I guess it comes standard with a Rails 5 install?).  The step I'm stuck on is the "Deploy the Project" step- my attempt to run "eb create" returns the 401 response I mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this question was awhile ago but for those looking for the solution to this issue you need to add the following permissions to your IAM account.

AWSCodeCommitPowerUser
AWSCodeCommitFullAccess

Comment: Why though...?  This doesn't seem in any way related to the error message, is this just AWS sloppiness?

Comment: @JTWolgamott It's a configuration validation error, so aws can't validate that the user has permission to configure the account which in this case is a deploy.  AWS has IAM accounts so that you can assign developer responsibilities without giving any one user complete control. These permissions just give the specified user permission to deploy/init etc.